# How do I edit the presProps.xml file with ApachePoi

Tags: apache-poi, powerpoint

I need to have a powerpoint loop until the user hits the escape key. Through saving and unzipping the file after checking the "Loop continuously until 'ESC'" option in the powerpoint's Slideshow Setup options I have a diff of the file that changes(ppt/presProps.xml)

Not fixed:

```
<p:presentationPr xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
   <p:showPr showNarration="1">
      <p:present />
      <p:sldAll />
      <p:penClr>
         <a:prstClr val="red" />
      </p:penClr>
      <p:extLst>
         <p:ext uri="{EC167BDD-8182-4AB7-AECC-EB403E3ABB37}">
            <p14:laserClr xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main">
               <a:srgbClr val="FF0000" />
            </p14:laserClr>
         </p:ext>
         <p:ext uri="{2FDB2607-1784-4EEB-B798-7EB5836EED8A}">
            <p14:showMediaCtrls xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="1" />
         </p:ext>
      </p:extLst>
   </p:showPr>
   <p:extLst>
      <p:ext uri="{E76CE94A-603C-4142-B9EB-6D1370010A27}">
         <p14:discardImageEditData xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="0" />
      </p:ext>
      <p:ext uri="{D31A062A-798A-4329-ABDD-BBA856620510}">
         <p14:defaultImageDpi xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="220" />
      </p:ext>
      <p:ext uri="{FD5EFAAD-0ECE-453E-9831-46B23BE46B34}">
         <p15:chartTrackingRefBased xmlns:p15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2012/main" val="0" />
      </p:ext>
   </p:extLst>
</p:presentationPr>
```

Fixed:

```
<p:presentationPr xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships">
   <p:showPr loop="1" showNarration="1">
      <p:present />
      <p:sldAll />
      <p:penClr>
         <a:prstClr val="red" />
      </p:penClr>
      <p:extLst>
         <p:ext uri="{EC167BDD-8182-4AB7-AECC-EB403E3ABB37}">
            <p14:laserClr xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main">
               <a:srgbClr val="FF0000" />
            </p14:laserClr>
         </p:ext>
         <p:ext uri="{2FDB2607-1784-4EEB-B798-7EB5836EED8A}">
            <p14:showMediaCtrls xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="1" />
         </p:ext>
      </p:extLst>
   </p:showPr>
   <p:extLst>
      <p:ext uri="{E76CE94A-603C-4142-B9EB-6D1370010A27}">
         <p14:discardImageEditData xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="0" />
      </p:ext>
      <p:ext uri="{D31A062A-798A-4329-ABDD-BBA856620510}">
         <p14:defaultImageDpi xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="220" />
      </p:ext>
      <p:ext uri="{FD5EFAAD-0ECE-453E-9831-46B23BE46B34}">
         <p15:chartTrackingRefBased xmlns:p15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2012/main" val="0" />
      </p:ext>
   </p:extLst>
</p:presentationPr>
```

Element diff:

```
3c3
<    <p:showPr showNarration="1">
---
>    <p:showPr loop="1" showNarration="1">
```

It looks like it's on a p element within the presentation element but I can't figure out how to set that attribute within POI.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a quick hack to show the modifications of package parts, which are not accessible via the API. As XmlBeans sets the loop attributes as `"true"` instead of `"1"`, it might be necessary to set it via the [XmlCursor API](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/conNavigatingXMLwithCursors.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open("headers.pptx", PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
    try (XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(opc)) {
        PackagePart presProps = ppt.getPackage().getPart(PackagingURIHelper.createPartName("/ppt/presProps.xml"));
        PresentationPrDocument doc = PresentationPrDocument.Factory.parse(presProps.getInputStream());
        CTPresentationProperties pr = doc.getPresentationPr();
        CTShowProperties showPr = pr.isSetShowPr() ? pr.getShowPr() : pr.addNewShowPr();
        showPr.setLoop(true);
        presProps.clear();
        try (OutputStream os = presProps.getOutputStream()) {
            doc.save(os);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great except that now one page of my powerpoint is off the page, any idea if powerpoint is picking it up as a different version or something?