# How to change ppt presentation mode using apache-poi or another 3-rd library?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've been working on a project which needs to display a PPT file in "kiosk"  presentation mode.
In a PPTX file, I can extract it like a zip file and rewrite the presProps.xml which contains properties like "p:showPr useTimings="0" p:present", and I can change the mode by rewriting "p:present" to "p:kiosk".
And I have just figured out that I can use apache-poi OPCPackage to do that.
(e.g. [How do I edit the presProps.xml file with ApachePoi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49240059/how-do-i-edit-the-presprops-xml-file-with-apachepoi))

However, in a PPT file, I cannot do that like above. Is there any way that I can change the presentation mode of a PPT file.
Or can I use apache-poi to convert a PPT file to a PPTX file so that the solution above can work?

Thx.

Comment: At least the [MS-PPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd908143.aspx) says, there's a field for it. But POI doesn't map RecordTypes.SSDocInfoAtom (HSLF) to a class, so you need to implement it yourself ... if you need help in adapting (copy&pasting) the existing HSLF classes, drop me a note at the POI user list.

Answer (score 1):

A `*.ppt` file is a `PowerPoint` file stored in binary file format. This is what [org.apache.poi.hslf](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hslf/) is made for. Entry point is the [HSLFSlideShow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlideShow.html).

All the office binary formats have in common that they are streams of `Record` data records to describe the document. For `PowerPoint` the specification is here: [[MS-PPT]: PowerPoint (.ppt) Binary File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313106(v=office.12).aspx).

For your requirement there is [DocumentContainer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd947357.aspx) having an optional [SlideShowDocInfoAtom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd908143.aspx) set. There `F - fKioskMode (1 bit)` can be set to set kiosk mode.

The `DocumentContainer` can be got via [HSLFSlideShow.getDocumentRecord](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hslf/usermodel/HSLFSlideShow.html#getDocumentRecord--) using `apache poi`. But then the support from `apache poi` ends because the `Record` `SlideShowDocInfoAtom` is not implemented until now.

But using an own class `SlideShowDocInfoAtom` which extends `RecordAtom` we can implement this.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.record.Record;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.record.RecordAtom;

public class HSLFSlideShowToKioskMode {

 // not really necessary, only for debug actions
 private static void hexDumpRecord(Record record) throws Exception {
  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  record.writeOut(out);
  out.flush();
  byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
  out.close();
  String hexDump = new java.math.BigInteger(data).toString(16);
  System.out.println(hexDump);
 }

 // method for get/set SlideShowDocInfoAtom
 private static SlideShowDocInfoAtom getSlideShowDocInfoAtom(HSLFSlideShow slideshow) throws Exception {
  SlideShowDocInfoAtom slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord = null;
  Record record = slideshow.getDocumentRecord().findFirstOfType(1025);
System.out.println(record.toString() + " type:" + record.getRecordType());
hexDumpRecord(record);
  if (record != null) { // we must not create new SlideShowDocInfoAtom
   // get present data
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   record.writeOut(out);
   out.flush();
   byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
   out.close();
   // create new SlideShowDocInfoAtom from data
   slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord = new SlideShowDocInfoAtom(data);
   // replace old record with new SlideShowDocInfoAtom
   slideshow.getDocumentRecord().addChildBefore(
    slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord,
    record
   );
   slideshow.getDocumentRecord().removeChild(record);
  } else { // we must create new SlideShowDocInfoAtom
   slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord = new SlideShowDocInfoAtom();
   // add this SlideShowDocInfoAtom before EndDocumentAtom
   slideshow.getDocumentRecord().addChildBefore(
    slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord,
    slideshow.getDocumentRecord().findFirstOfType(1002) // 1002 = 0x3ea = RT_EndDocumentAtom
   );
  }
  return slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  HSLFSlideShow slideshow = new HSLFSlideShow(new FileInputStream("Presentation.ppt"));

  SlideShowDocInfoAtom slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord = getSlideShowDocInfoAtom(slideshow);
  slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord.setfKioskMode(true);
  slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord.setRestartTime(300000);
hexDumpRecord(slideShowDocInfoAtomRecord);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("PresentationKiosk.ppt");
  slideshow.write(out);
  out.close();
  slideshow.close();
 }

 //class SlideShowDocInfoAtom 
 //having methods for manipulating the [SlideShowDocInfoAtom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd908143.aspx)
 private static class SlideShowDocInfoAtom extends RecordAtom {

  private byte[] data;

  public SlideShowDocInfoAtom() {
   this.data = new byte[] {

    //header
    (byte)0x01, (byte)0x00, //MUST be 0x0001 (little endian)
    (byte)0x01, (byte)0x04, //MUST be 0x0401 = RT_SlideShowDocInfoAtom (little endian)
    (byte)0x50, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //MUST be 0x00000050 (little endian)

    //R         //G         //B         //isRGB
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xFE, //penColor green

    (byte)0xe0, (byte)0x93, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x00, //restartTime 300000 ms (0x493e0, little endian)

    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //startSlide, only if fUseSlideRange is set

    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //endSlide, only if fUseSlideRange is set

    //namedShow (64 bytes), only filled if there are named shows and fDocUseNamedShow is set, else all 0x00
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //8
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //16
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //24
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //32
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //40
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //48
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //56
    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, //64

    //H                 G                  F          E           D                C              B               A
    //fLoopContinuously,fWillSkipNarration,fKioskMode,fBrowseMode,fDocUseNamedShow,fUseSlideRange,fWillSkipBuilds,fAutoAdvance
    (byte)Integer.parseInt("00010000", 2), //only fBrowseMode is set

    //              I
    //0,0,0,0,0,0,0,fHideScrollBar
    (byte)Integer.parseInt("00000000", 2),

    (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 //unused

   };
  }

  public SlideShowDocInfoAtom(byte[] data) {
   this.data = data;
  }

  public void setfKioskMode(boolean on) {
   byte HGFEDCBA = this.data[84];
   HGFEDCBA &= (byte)Integer.parseInt("110011111", 2); //fKioskMode and fBrowseMode = 0
   if (on) HGFEDCBA |= (byte)Integer.parseInt("10100000", 2); //fLoopContinuously = 1 and fKioskMode = 1
   else HGFEDCBA |= (byte)Integer.parseInt("00010000", 2); //fBrowseMode = 1
   this.data[84] = HGFEDCBA;
  }

  public void setRestartTime(long milliseconds) {
   //must be greater than or equal 300000
   if (milliseconds < 300000) return;
   this.data[12] = (byte) (milliseconds & 0xFF);
   this.data[13] = (byte) ((milliseconds >> 8) & 0xFF);
   this.data[14] = (byte) ((milliseconds >> 16) & 0xFF);
   this.data[15] = (byte) ((milliseconds >> 24) & 0xFF);
  }

  //TODO: other setters

  @Override
  public void writeOut(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
   out.write(data);
  }

  @Override
  public long getRecordType() { return 1025; }
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Axel - in case you would like to get more involved in the project, please drop me a note.